# Is it possible to have different members in a class document have different colours?

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I am using visual studio 2008 professional and was wondering, how can I have different colours for method calls within class methods, and for properties/fields? This would be good as it would give me a quick visual overview of what my class has too much of (e.g. 20 fields and 2 methods - which will give me some interesting information on my design - not that I do this, anyway).

Ideally, I'd like to have these members highlighted, as when you step through.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Out of the box, I do not believe it is possible in Visual Studio 2008. You might need an aftermarket addon to implement this specific functionality. You could always look into [Visual Assist X](http://www.wholetomato.com/tour.asp?syntax), although it is a commercial product.